# Why default cross sell layout doesn't show anything?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2.6, cross-sells

I'm trying to show cross sell on product page anfd I'm using default logic:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell" name="catalog.product.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title"xsi:type="string">Accessories</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
    </block>   
</block>
```

But it doesn't work.

catalog_product_view_xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>   
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_custom_block" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.price" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
    <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
    <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
    <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product_view_custom_block"/>
    <!--<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" remove="true"/>-->
    <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.review"/>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_custom.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_config" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/config.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="prev_next_products" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/prev_next.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="prev_next_products" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_property" template="product/view/g4b_product_property.phtml" />
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_addthis_links" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addthis.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\RickSnippet" name="rich_snippet" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/rich_snippet.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block" ifconfig="porto_settings/product/main_custom_block" before="product.info.main" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block.phtml"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block2" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block2.phtml"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product.clearer" after="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/clearer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="product_view_main_custom_block2" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="side_popup" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/side_popup.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>


    <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" remove="true"/>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_plus.tab" as="g4b_product_plus" template="product/view/g4b_product_plus.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Advantages</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_features.tab" as="g4b_product_features" template="product/view/g4b_product_features.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Features</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_gommini.tab" as="g4b_product_gommini" template="product/view/g4b_product_gommini.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="false" name="title" xsi:type="string">Gommini</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_cad.tab" as="g4b_product_cad" template="product/view/g4b_product_cad.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Type/CAD Data</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
      <block name="g4b_product_cad.tab" remove="true"/>
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" name="upsell.tab" as="upselltab" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
           <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Type/CAD Data</argument>
           <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
        </arguments>
     </block>
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell" name="catalog.product.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Accessories</argument>
            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                   name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_accessories.tab" as="g4b_product_accessories" template="product/view/g4b_product_accessories.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Accessories</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
      <block name="g4b_product_accessories.tab" remove="true"/>
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_video.tab" as="g4b_product_video" template="product/view/g4b_product_video.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Video</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="g4b_product_download.tab" as="g4b_product_download" template="product/view/g4b_product_download.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="false" name="title" xsi:type="string">Download</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
      <block name="reviews.tab" remove="true"></block>
      <block name="g4b_product_gommini.tab" remove="true"></block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell" name="catalog.product.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Accessories</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
```

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Maybe it's caused by Crosssell.php ?

Comment: Have you tried after cache flush?

Actually in your code I found like this: `<argument translate="true" name="title"xsi:type="string">Accessories</argument>` But it should be like this : `<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Accessories</argument>`

Comment: nothing even with cache flushed

Comment: Ok, add below code in `vendor/autoload.php` you will have error if is there any error in code.

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
`

Comment: there aren't errors

Comment: have you assgined crosssell products to that product from admin, is that full page shows balnk or only crosssell products not showing?

Comment: Only cross sell product are blank.
In the cart page they are visible but not in product page

Comment: Please share your full xml file code.

Comment: done. Now on console there is this: Active resource loading counts reached a per-frame limit while the tab was in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is brought to the foreground. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more details